# Critical error during OpenCms initialization: The OpenCms setup wizard is still enabled?

Tags: opencms

Trying to run my OpenCms application as Java SpringBoot application.

For the first time, we need to run DB setup page so at that time am getting exceptions like below.

Critical error during OpenCms initialization: The OpenCms setup wizard is still enabled

> org.opencms.main.CmsException: Critical error during OpenCms initialization: The OpenCms setup wizard is still enabled.
>       at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.setErrorCondition(OpenCmsCore.java:370) [opencms-core-10.5.2.jar:10.5.2]
>       at org.opencms.main.CmsInitException.setErrorCondition(CmsInitException.java:113) [opencms-core-10.5.2.jar:10.5.2]
>       at org.opencms.main.CmsInitException.(CmsInitException.java:70) [opencms-core-10.5.2.jar:10.5.2]
>       at org.opencms.main.CmsInitException.(CmsInitException.java:56) [opencms-core-10.5.2.jar:10.5.2]
>       at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.initContext(OpenCmsCore.java:1516) [opencms-core-10.5.2.jar:10.5.2]
>       at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.upgradeRunlevel(OpenCmsCore.java:2090) [opencms-core-10.5.2.jar:10.5.2]
>       at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsServlet.init(OpenCmsServlet.java:253) [opencms-core-10.5.2.jar:10.5.2]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:78) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:256) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:181) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at com.test.OpenCmsApp.main(OpenCmsApp.java:50) [classes/:na]

[2m2017-09-18 14:34:02.072[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7936[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet [openCmsServlet] in web application [] threw load() exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Critical error during OpenCms initialization: The OpenCms setup wizard is still enabled.
    at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsServlet.init(OpenCmsServlet.java:261) ~[opencms-core-10.5.2.jar:10.5.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:78) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:256) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:181) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.test.OpenCmsApp.main(OpenCmsApp.java:50) [classes/:na]

[2m2017-09-18 14:34:02.072[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7936[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet [openCmsServlet] in web application [] threw load() exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your error description I cannot fully understand when exactly you get this error message.
If you get it after the installation successfully finished, please check, the `opencms.properties` files. There is a variable `wizard.enabled` at the end of the file. It must be set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for response..!

Comment: Yeah, you are correct if we have done DB setup part. But for the first time, we have to do the DB setup part, for that am unable to launch the (http:<host>:<port>/opencms/setup) page itself.

Am trying to deploy the OpenCms war in Spring-boot embedded tomcat, so when trying to start the application at that time am getting these issues.